# update tempvar using multithreading vba

Tags: multithreading, vba, ms-access

I have written multithreading functions that create multiple copies of the main Access Database file. Each copy then runs a specified loop function, "RunForVBA". the total number of loop iterations is divided by the number of access copies, and each copy runs part of the total loop count. this works very well but Im trying to put together a single progress bar Form that tracks total progress af all the threads. each copy updates the main progress bar form for each loop iteration.

Im trying to use a TempVar in the main database to record the total counter and reference the progress bar to this tempvar. this kind of works but does the tempvar is not updated for each loop in each instance. Im have no idea why it only partially works.

code as follows

```
    Dim para As clsMultiThread
    Dim lloop As Long

    lloop = 600

    Debug.Print "lets go!!"

    Set para = New clsMultiThread
    DoCmd.OpenForm "ProgressBar"

    Call Forms("ProgressBar").SetProgressBarParameters("Testing ProgressBar Again", "Message: It kind of works!!", lloop)
    Call para.SetThreads(12)
    Call para.MultiThreadLoop("RunForVBA", 1, lloop)

    Debug.Print TempVars("ProgressBarCounter").value
    DoCmd.Close ObjectType:=acForm, ObjectName:="ProgressBar"
```

the multithread function runs "RunForVBA"

code as follows:

```
Sub RunForVBA(seqFrom As Long, seqTo As Long)

    Dim lTimer As Long
    Dim i, iInc As Integer
    Dim x As Double

    Dim appAccess As Access.Application
    Dim tvProgBarCtr As TempVar

    Set appAccess = New Access.Application
    Set appAccess = GetObject(, "Access.Application")

    Set tvProgBarCtr = appAccess.TempVars("ProgressBarCounter")

    lTimer = GetTickCount

    For i = seqFrom To seqTo
        tvProgBarCtr.value = tvProgBarCtr.value + 1
        DoEvents
        Sleep (400)
    Next i

    Set appAccess = Nothing

End Sub
```

Ive tried changing the sleep times, changing the number of threads, among others. Is there a maximum number of {GetObject(, "Access.Application") } that I can do?

Im not sure why it partially works and not totally or none at all. with the functions above, the TempVar generally finishes on anything between 250 and 300, not the 600 for the total loop count.

Comment: instead of trying to have all the "threads" do an update to a single progress counter, have a separate progress counter for each thread. .... then have the progress bar incremented by a watchdog program that tallies all the progress counters

Comment: absolutely brilliantly simple. works so well. thanks